# How to force a website to load at the top?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am developing a parallax website. For some reason, whenever I refresh the page, it always loads at the bottom instead of the top. Does anyone know how to overwrite this? Or is it because there's something wrong with my code, that causes the browser to load at the bottom?

I will provide the code if needed, but this is more of a general question. Just want to know the reason why a browser would reload at the bottom instead at the top. (Tested on Chrome & Firefox).

Alright here is the code. First of all, its HTML5 and loading jQuery 1.8.0

Code:

```
<!-- Section #1 / Intro -->
<section id="first" class="story" data-speed="8" data-type="background">        
    <div class="heart" data-type="sprite" data-offsetY="100" data-Xposition="50%" data-speed="-2"></div>        

    <article>

        <img src="images/blackout.png" alt="tutorial-title" width="auto" height="auto" />

    </article>
</section>

<!-- Section #2 / Background Only -->
<section id="second" class="story2" data-speed="5" data-type="background">
    <article>
        <h2>Background Only</h2>
            <p>my text stuff appears here</p>   
    </article>
</section>
```

So, everytime I refresh the browser, the website always loads on Section #2 instead of section #1.

Comment: can you explain more clearly what you mean?

Comment: is it working live please send the link

Answer (score 0):

you can use this

```
$("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 0);
```

Comment: What have you tried? You have an online sandbox so we can see the problem? It is hard to actually understand from some random lines of code without visual feedback and seeing the source code. You can also set up a jsfiddle.